# Changing the animation duration of a CAShapeLayer transform in swift

Tags: ios, swift, vector, transform

I am using `CATransform3DMakeScale` to resize a vector graphic in an iPad app. It is animated by default and I would like to be able to change the duration of this animation. Any advice?

Comment: Might want take look- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18206430/ios-translation-and-scale-animation

Answer (score 1):

If it's layers you want to adjust the duration try `+ setAnimationDuration:`

**Swift**

```
class func setAnimationDuration(_ dur: CFTimeInterval)
```

**Objective-C**

```
+ (void)setAnimationDuration:(CFTimeInterval)duration
```

> Sets the animation duration used by all animations within this
>   transaction group.

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CATransaction_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/CATransaction/setAnimationDuration: