# How to chain CGAffineTransform together in separate animations?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, animation, cgaffinetransform

I need two animations on a UIView:

1. Make the view move down and slightly grow.
2. Make the view grow even bigger about its new center.

When I attempt to do that, the second animation starts in a weird location but ends up in the right location and size. How would I make the second animation start at the same position that the first animation ended in?

[image]

```
#import "ViewController.h"

static const CGFloat kStartX = 100.0;
static const CGFloat kStartY = 20.0;
static const CGFloat kStartSize = 30.0;
static const CGFloat kEndCenterY = 200.0;

@interface ViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView *box;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];

  self.box = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(kStartX, kStartY, kStartSize, kStartSize)];
  self.box.backgroundColor = [UIColor brownColor];
  [self.view addSubview:self.box];

  [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0
                        delay:1.0
       usingSpringWithDamping:1.0
        initialSpringVelocity:0.0
                      options:0
                   animations:^{
                     self.box.transform = [self _transformForSize:50.0 centerY:kEndCenterY];
                   }
                   completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0
                                           delay:1.0
                          usingSpringWithDamping:1.0
                           initialSpringVelocity:0.0
                                         options:0
                                      animations:^{
                                        self.box.transform = [self _transformForSize:100.0 centerY:kEndCenterY];
                                      }
                                      completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                                      }];
                   }];
}

- (CGAffineTransform)_transformForSize:(CGFloat)newSize centerY:(CGFloat)newCenterY
{
  CGFloat newScale = newSize / kStartSize;
  CGFloat startCenterY = kStartY + kStartSize / 2.0;
  CGFloat deltaY = newCenterY - startCenterY;
  CGAffineTransform translation = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0, deltaY);
  CGAffineTransform scaling = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(newScale, newScale);
  return CGAffineTransformConcat(scaling, translation);
}

@end
```

There's one caveat: I'm forced to use setTransform rather than setFrame. I'm not using a brown box in my real code. My real code is using a complex UIView subclass that doesn't scale smoothly when I use setFrame.

Comment: so you want the second animation to stay at same position and just grow bigger ?

Comment: @TejaNandamuri Correct. There should be no disconnect between the first and second animation.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18206430/ios-translation-and-scale-animation (I know it won't solve your problem due to not being able to change the `frame`, but might be useful to anyone else coming across this question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like it *might* be a UIKit bug with how UIViews resolve their layout when you apply a transform on top of an existing one.  I was able to at least get the starting coordinates for the second animation correct by doing the following, at the very beginning of the second completion block:

```
  [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0
                        delay:1.0
       usingSpringWithDamping:1.0
        initialSpringVelocity:0.0
                      options:0
                   animations:^{
                     self.box.transform = [self _transformForSize:50.0 centerY:kEndCenterY];
                   }
                   completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     // <new code here>
                     CGRect newFrame = self.box.frame;
                     self.box.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
                     self.box.frame = newFrame;
                     // </new code>
                     [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0
                                           delay:1.0
                          usingSpringWithDamping:1.0
                           initialSpringVelocity:0.0
                                         options:0
                                      animations:^{
                                        self.box.transform = [self _transformForSize:100.0 centerY:kEndCenterY];
                                      }
                                      completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                                      }];
                   }];
```

Using the same call to `-_transformForSize:centerY:` results in the same Y translation being performed in the second animation, though, so the box ends up further down in the view than you want when all is said and done.

To fix this, you need to calculate deltaY based on the box's starting Y coordinate at the *end* of the first animation rather than the original, constant Y coordinate:

```
- (CGAffineTransform)_transformForSize:(CGFloat)newSize centerY:(CGFloat)newCenterY
{
  CGFloat newScale = newSize / kStartSize;
  // Replace this line:
  CGFloat startCenterY = kStartY + kStartSize / 2.0;
  // With this one:
  CGFloat startCenterY = self.box.frame.origin.y + self.box.frame.size.height / 2.0;
  // </replace>
  CGFloat deltaY = newCenterY - startCenterY;
  CGAffineTransform translation = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0, deltaY);
  CGAffineTransform scaling = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(newScale, newScale);
  return CGAffineTransformConcat(scaling, translation);
}
```

and it should do the trick.

**UPDATE**

I should say, I consider this "trick" more of a work-around than an actual solution, but the box's frame and transform look correct at each stage of the animation pipeline, so if there's a true "solution" it's eluding me at the moment.  This trick at least solves the translation problem for you, so you can experiment with your more complex view hierarchy and see how far you get.

Comment: Resetting the transform does indeed solve the problem. I wish I knew the reason though. It pains me as a computer scientist to apply voodoo fixes.

Comment: Agreed.  I think if you truly want to solve your issue and stay in "transform space" instead of moving between via "transform" -> "frame" -> "transform", you'll probably need to tweak what I've done with your transform, take out the translation to "frame space" in the completion block for the first animation, and have the second transform be something more like `self.box.transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(self.box.transform, [self _transformForSize:100.0 centerY:kEndCenterY]);`  Ultimately you'll want a second transform that can be applied on top of the first.